# Share Button in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a share button and the working of that button is that if user click then it will open a popup box and display the URL and copy button where user click on copy button then URL will copy 
here is my code

```
    <ul id="playlist">
             <table class="table table-striped" id="userTbl" >
    <tbody>     
    <?php while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
   <tr>
   <td> <li><a href="<?php echo $row['url'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></a></li></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['artist'];?></td>  
    <td class="one"><?php echo $row['album_name'];?></td>
    <td class="one"><a  href="download.php?file=<?php echo $row['url'];?>..<?php echo $row['name'];?>">

        <img src="images/download.png" alt="Download" width="30" height="30">
</a></td>
    <td class="one">
        <a  id ="myBtn" href="#">
        <img src="images/share.png"  alt="share" width="30" height="30">
</a></td>
  </tr> 
 //popup box
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <input type="text" value="play.php?file=<?php echo $row['URL_ID'];?>" readonly="readonly" id="myInput" />
    <button onclick="copyfunc()">Copy</button>
  </div>

</div>
       <?php }?> 
</tbody>
   </table>
```

in this code i will display all the data from the database in the table where copy code work perfect but problem is that popup box is opened only for first index later it does not open can any one me where i am wrong.

Comment: I can't actually see any code which would open the modal at all. Can you clarify that? However I expect the problem is likely to be that because of your loop you are create lots of modals with the id "myModal". When you run code to open the modal, how do you expect the page to be able to tell the difference between them? It can't, so it just opens the first one it finds. The whole point of an ID is to uniquely identify something. if you produce lots of objects with the same ID, then the concept doesn't work.

Comment: You need to find a way to uniquely identify each modal. Perhaps giving it an ID based on a unique field from the $row would work.

Comment: Everything is work perfectly but problem is that "myModel" Is open only for one time

Comment: I know. You already said that in the question. Do you understand my comments?

Comment: Ohh i did not see your second comment now i understand thank you